# How to solve this problem with a multi variable function?

Tags: multivariable-calculus, inverse-function

I have this assignment given to me with $f: \mathbb{R}^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}, \ f(x,y)=xy-y^2$ to find $f^{-1}([0,1])$.

I started by finding the edge cases for $x$ where $f(x,y)=0 \Leftrightarrow x = y$ and $f(x,y)=1 \Leftrightarrow x = \dfrac{1}{y}+y$. I end up with $y \leq x \leq \dfrac{1}{y}+y$.

I just do not know how to formulate the answer because I know that $f^{-1}([0,1])$ generates a set or an interval.

This question is related to another assignment where I have to prove (or disprove) its surjection.

Comment: It would help Readers respond if you shared what class this assignment comes from. Methods appropriate for a high school course would like differ from an upper level college course (e.g. third term calculus or topology).

Comment: This assignment is for an university student (I am studying computer science and its from an introductory to linear algebra course)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We factor $f$ as $f(x,y)=(x-y)y$. Clearly if $y=0$, then $x$ can be anything. Pick $y\neq0$. Then $(x-y)$ must be between $0$ and $\frac{1}{y}$, so $x$ is between $y$ and $y+\frac{1}{y}$. We write this simply as $$f^{-1}([0,1])=\{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0<y\leq x\leq y +\frac{1}{y}\}\cup \{(x,y)\in \mathbb{R}^2:0>y\geq x\geq y +\frac{1}{y}\}\cup\mathbb{R}\times\{0\}$$

Comment: That was some nice mental gymnastics but I got it now. Thanks.

Comment: One mistake I think you did is $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R}^2$ that should be $(x,y) \in \mathbb{R} \times \mathbb{R}\setminus\{0\}$

Comment: @MohamedHousseinDouici In which part? You specified that $f:\mathbb{R}^2\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: you wrote $0 < y \leq x \leq y + \dfrac{1}{y}$ but $\dfrac{1}{y}$ can't obviously be $\dfrac{1}{0}$ as $y\in \mathbb{R}$

Comment: @MohamedHousseinDouici In that same inequality we have $0<y$ which guarantees that $y\neq 0$